# How do you download secured image

Tags: php, image, download

I am trying to download a secured image, I am able to download other images except the link below.

https://store.bbcomcdn.com/images/store/skuimage/sku_EVL4900077/image_skuEVL4900077_largeImage_X_450_white.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    function downloadFile ($url, $path) {

  $newfname = $path;
  $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
  if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

    if ($newf)
    while(!feof($file)) {
      fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
    }
  }

  if ($file) {
    fclose($file);
  }

  if ($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
  }
 }

downloadFile ("https://store.bbcomcdn.com/images/store/skuimage/sku_EVL4900077/image_skuEVL4900077_largeImage_X_450_white.jpg", "name.jpg");
?>
```

Comment: And what is actual problem?

Comment: It doesn't download the image

Comment: Is there any error in the PHP log? **HINT** you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you CURL the file. Just make sure you set all the headers they seem to be checking. The following script worked like a charm:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://store.bbcomcdn.com/images/store/skuimage/sku_EVL4900077/image_skuEVL4900077_largeImage_X_450_white.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Expect: 100-continue',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive'
]);
$st = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents('name.jpg', $st);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job!!